# Complex positioning of multiple figures

Tags: graphics, floats, titles

I have multiple figures that are included in my tex file. My tex code is :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=0.7\linewidth]{1.jpg}
    \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=0.7\linewidth]{1.jpg}
    \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=0.7\linewidth]{1.jpg}
    \caption{Test}
    \label{figTest}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and the output is like this:
[image]

Now I want to put two other images as horizontal title and vertical title for the group of the three images. The horizontal and vertical titles are:

[image]

[image]

and I want the output to be like this:

[image]

Is this possible in LaTeX? if so, how please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some possibilities to achieve this:

- Use the graphics files as side/bottom panels (Change the width/height to appropiate settings specific to the dimensions of the files (not known to me)
- Use a direct font approach, i.e. with text as side/bottom legends

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c@{}c@{}}
      \multirow{-6}{*}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,angle=90]{vertical.jpg}}
        &
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=0.7\linewidth]{1.jpg} \tabularnewline
        \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=0.7\linewidth]{1.jpg} \tabularnewline
        \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=0.7\linewidth]{1.jpg} \tabularnewline
      \end{tabular} \tabularnewline
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,height=1cm]{horizontal.jpg}}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test}
    \label{figTest}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c@{}c@{}}
      \multirow{-4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\LARGE \bfseries Error (mm)}}
        &
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=0.7\linewidth]{1.jpg} \tabularnewline
        \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=0.7\linewidth]{1.jpg} \tabularnewline
        \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=0.7\linewidth]{1.jpg} \tabularnewline
      \end{tabular} \tabularnewline
      & \tabularnewline
      & \LARGE \bfseries Time (s)  \tabularnewline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Other Test}
    \label{figOtherTest}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `pdftex` option to `graphicx` should never be specified.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I need to use the additional graphics because of their fonts unless it is possible to set the font to Calibri?

Answer (score 4):

No need of fancy packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\makebox[0pt][r]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
  \hspace{.5cm}%
  \includegraphics[height=.5cm,width=3cm]{example-image}%
}\hspace{.2cm}}%
\begin{tabular}{c@{}}
\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
\includegraphics[height=.5cm,width=3cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test}\label{figTest}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]